# (.text+0x0): multiple definition of '_start'

Tags: linux, assembly, gcc

I'm trying to assemble an assembly file as followed. The executable file should output the command arguments.

```
.text
.globl _start

_start:
    popl %ecx
vnext:
    popl %ecx
    test %ecx,%ecx
    jz exit
    movl %ecx,%ebx
    xorl %edx,%edx
strlen:
    movb (%ebx),%al
    inc %edx
    inc %ebx
    test %al,%al
    jnz strlen
    movb $10,-1(%ebx)
    movl $4, %eax
    movl $1, %ebx
    int $0x80
    jmp vnext
exit:
    movl $1, %eax
    xorl %ebx, %ebx
    int $0x80
```

When i use as and ld to assemble and link, no error occurs. But when i use gcc, errors as followed.

```
# gcc -m32 -no-pie arg_str.s -o arg_str
/tmp/ccXBtNYB.o: In function '_start':                                                                                                                             
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of '_start'                   
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib32/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here                                  
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../../lib32/crt1.o: In function '_start':                                                                           
(.text+0x28): undefined reference to 'main'                                                                                                                                   
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

It seems that gcc requires `main` function as the start of a program and does not allow the use of `_start`. Any solution to avoid that error?

Comment: You forgot `-nostdlib` to build code that defines its own _start.  (And which doesn't use any functions from libc.so)

Comment: Also `-nostartfiles`